# Laravel data not updating from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I just implement the crud in my application And update api does not Working I don't know why. It is not throwing any error when I hit this api from postman.

```
public function update(int $id,Request $request)
{
    // return $request->all();
    $rules = [
        'question' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        $rules
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                __('messages.ERRORKEY') => $validator->errors(),
                'message' => __('messages.VALIDATION_MESSAGE')
            ],
            env('ERRORCODE', 422)
        );
    }
    $question = Question::with('options')->find($id);
    $question->update(['question' => $request->question]);
    
    return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "Question saved successfully.",
        "data" => $question
    ]);
}
```

Comment: are you getting options with `$question?`.